# write .htaccess to make all the files n folders present in a folder to be served on my website when in maintenance mode (403 (forbidden mode))?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have the following file structure in cPanel

```
web_root_folder_
               |____.neverDelete/_____
               |                     |_____img/logo-30.png
               |                     |_____js/error-page.js
               |                     |_____css/error-page.css
               |
               |____403.shtml
               |
               |____.htaccess
```

I wanted to write `.htaccess` with some code that puts the website in 'maintenance mode'.
So...I wrote `403.shtml` page, which uses external css, javascript and images stored in `.neverDelete` folder.

I wrote the following code in `.htaccess`

```
# The WORKING CODE (Too Long )
Deny From All
<FilesMatch 404-layout.min.css>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch logo-small-transparent-30.png>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch error-page.js>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

This code successfully worked. It implemented a `403(forbidden)` for all files except the 3 files (mentioned in `.htaccess` file)

but, I want to make all the files n folders present in `.neverDelete/` to be served on my website when in maintenance mode.

So i visited http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory to get help. I wrote the code in `.htaccess` below that actually gave in a `500(server error)`.

```
# WRONG CODE
Deny From All
<Directory .neverDelete/ >
    Allow From All
</Directory>
```

How can I make all the files n folders present in `.neverDelete/` to be served on my website when in `maintenance mode`.

Comment: _“I dont know why it did not worked”_ - because of the _context_ this directive is valid in.

Comment: Sorry could not understand what you just said...does the problem lies in the syntax in .htaccess? or The usage of that code itself is completely invalid?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory: _“Context: server config, virtual host”_ If you don’t know what that means, click on `Context`, it leads to the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification sir. Your clarification helped me to get the whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CBroe

In the `.htaccess` file, we can't use a `<Directory>` container, since the `.htaccess` file itself defines the directory.

Since `.htaccess` defines the directory...we can put a `.htaccess` file in the `.neverDelete/` directory with the following code

```
Allow from all
```

This will make the contents of the `.neverDelete/` directory always available.